# React router - different content if post in list vs own page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

[React router](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router) has very cool feature: if you have a list of items (Instagram for example) and if you click on one item, content opens in modal/overlay but if you copy-paste the link to new tab/window or share the link with a friend for example, it opens in its own page.

---

I would love to use this feature but I need to find a custom solution..

- My posts are very data heavy
- I've split posts data into 2 tables in database
- **1st** is very lightweight containing essential data: 4-5 columns
- **2nd** table is very heave, ~30 columns
- When user uses search filter, list updates only with data from **1st** table
- If user clicks on post, it will open in a modal/overlay
- I will recycle the data I already have (from **1st** table) and also get rest of the data from **2nd** table

---

However, when user shares the link or opens it in new tab/page, data from **1st** table is not present. I would need to integrate a conditional logic:

- If post opens in list view (modal/overlay), only get additinal **2nd** table data
- If it's opened in a new tab/window in its own page, get all the data, **1st** table included

**How could I integrate this with React router?** Has anyone already tried it? This would also allow to use different layout/components when user opens item in page view. Is there a way to check it?

Or is there a flaw in my logic? I imagine list would update very fast because it doesn't require huge amount of data and also would modal/overlay because it recycles some of the data.

I read all the docs, also searched online - didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modals in react router are great. I've used the pinterest example and adapted it to my own needs.

Ensure you do your check on state.modal===true in a master layout component to give you the modal styling.

you'll need to check if table 1 stuff is present in your state and dispatch an action to trigger the async call in componentDidMount. You should be fetching table 2 in all scenarios.